# Android Intent to save mail attachment

Tags: android

I have a program that I want the attached text file through other programs, then the file received and I can process it.
Be added to the list below ... 
How is it possible?

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/s4b4p1/8

Comment: It's unclear what your asking. Could you provide more details as well as any code you've already tried?

Answer (score 0):

To have your app listed for some kind of files, you have to define intent filter in you AndroidManifest.xml. Something like this:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.asd" />
        </intent-filter>
```